# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2 during file plot

Tags: python, file, indexing

I am trying to plot three files in the same figure with Matplotlib. However, in the third file I got this error:

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

```
import numpy  as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
k=0
InputFile = []
markers = ["o" , "s" , "D"]
colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

for i in range(1,4):
    InputFile.append("max-velocity-%s.out" %i)
    
for dname in InputFile:   
    k=k+1
    data=np.loadtxt(dname, skiprows= 3)
    x=data[:,1]
    y=data[:,2]
    plt.plot(x,y,color=colors[k-1], marker = markers[k-1])

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.xlabel(r'$t\,$(s)',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r'Max Velocity',fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Someone could help me out ?

Thanks.

Comment: You said it is size 2. Then index goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: alaniwi what index are you referring for ?

Comment: Second index of `data` - where you do `y=data[:,2]`

Comment: Remember that "axis 1" refers to **2nd** axis -- for the same reason.

Comment: What I am trying to do is read each file (three columns) and storage second column in X and third in Y. For this reason I did X=[:,1] and Y=[:,2]. It works for the first two files, but not to the third.

Comment: alaniwi, I found the error in my file. The third file has only tow columns.